# Python File Reading For Multiple Files Issue

Tags: python, csv

I have an odd issue in Python.  I am trying to grab several files from one drive and save them locally.  The Python code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd 

#read files 
DF1 = pd.read_csv('H:\Path\To\\csvfile1.csv')
DF2 = pd.read_csv('H:\Path\To\\csvfile2.csv')
DF3 = pd.read_csv('H:\Path\To\\csvfile3.csv')

#write files
DF1.to_csv('C:\Users\localdrive\csvfile1.csv')
DF2.to_csv('C:\Users\localdrive\csvfile2.csv')
DF3.to_csv('C:\Users\localdrive\csvfile3.csv')
```

Note the folder the files are saved in is identical.  For DF1 and DF2 everything works fine.  For DF3 it breaks and the error says:

IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename:

To the best of my knowledge, there is no difference in the source csv files (i.e. H:\Path\To\csvfile1.csv is identical to H:\Path\To\csvfile3.csv).  But obviously Python thinks otherwise.

Not sure how to troubleshoot.  I triple checked all paths/filenames/etc.

Here is the actual filename:

```
NG1 = pd.read_csv('H:\path\to\\natgasmdf.csv')
```

Even more strange, when I put the line above directly into iPython QT Console by itself, it works.  When I run the script with this in it, it fails.

Comment: All else aside, you should properly quote your backslashes (i.e. `'C:\\Users\\localdrive\\csvfile1.csv'` &c.) or use raw strings (i.e. `r'C:\Users\localdrive\csvfile1.csv'` &c.). Perhaps that will also solve your problem, depending on what the actual paths are.

Comment: do you have any /r /t etc in any of the file names strings that you have ? that is mostly the issue. change the to forward slash so that you can avoid this

Comment: Include the actual filename code that failed.

Comment: @Harvey please see above I added the actual filename.

Comment: @Dolda2000 tried all this with no luck.

Comment: try `pd.read_csv(r'H:\path\to\\natgasmdf.csv')` you have a `\n` in there

Comment: @NickHale unfortunately this didn't work

Comment: convert all of the backslashes to forward slashes or use escaped (doubled) backslashes. `\t` is a TAB character, so your path is `H:/path<TAB>o/natgasmdf.csv`.